# how to fix Declaration of PHPUnitLogger::flush() error?

Tags: php, phpunit, eclipse-pdt

I am using Eclipse pdt for PHP Developers Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2).
I created a Composer Project and I added those dependencies:

[image: dependencies]

then I created a TestCase file to test my class.
I could not change the superclass "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase".

I got this warning when creating the TestCase file

> There is no element 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' in the project
>   'PayementAPI'

then into the default TestCase Class created I changed the extends "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase" to "TestCase" and I added the import.

```
    <?php
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    include 'otherClass.php';

    /**
     * MyClass1 test case.
     */
    class MyClass1Test extends TestCase
    {
     ...
    }
```

Then I tried to run my class test as PHPUnit test but got this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of PHPUnitLogger::flush() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Util\Printer::flush(): void in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_printer\PHPUnitLogger.php on line 33

Answer (score -2):

Try one with a lower version of phpunit.phar, download the lower version [here](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.phar).